# look at this fql code it returning null

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

```
<?
     $fb_signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
     $page_id = $fb_signed_request["page"]["id"];
     $fb_like_status = $fb_signed_request["page"]["liked"];
     $fb_is_admin = ($fb_signed_request["page"]["admin"]==1)?TRUE:FALSE;
     $fql = "SELECT uid FROM page_admin WHERE page_id='" . $page_id . "'";

     $param = array(
      'method'    => 'fql.query',
      'query'     => $fql,
       'callback'  => ''
     );
     $fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);

     print_r ($fqlResult);
```

?>

I'm get the PAGE_ID ok, but FQLRESULT is null. I'm trying to get  the id of the owner of the page..

Answer (score 3):

Did you ask for manage_pages permission from the user?  Check what access was granted via calling `/me/permissions` to see the complete list of items granted.

Comment: When you prompt them to log in, you need to ask for the permissions. You don't get to set them, but rather you get to ask the user for them.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: I don't understand.  As the app developer, don't I need to set the permissions that the app needs?

Comment: You ask the user for the permissions.  They have the power to choose.  Remember, they get to reject certain permissions too, so it's your responsibility as the app developers to check `/me/permissions` to ensure you have the permission you asked the user for when they authorized your app.

Comment: How do I ask the user for the permissions?

Comment: in the FB.login(function(response){//handle response},{scope:'comma,separate,list,of,permissions'}).  Or there's a similar thing if you do it via the PHP code (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).